"Err:6", "W:", "E:" and "N:" messages after "sudo apt update"
I tried uninstall Docker and VS code from my Ubuntu 23.04 OS in my dual boot computer. The other OS in my dual boot computer is Windows 11 (This was the first OS of my computer prior to getting dual boot setup)
To uninstall Docker I entered the following in terminator as shown in https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-uninstall-docker-on-ubuntu/#:~:text=Commands%20Mentioned,configurations%2C%20images%2C%20and%20volumes. :
sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -aq) 
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker 
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-key del $(sudo apt-key list | grep Docker | awk ‘{print $2}’) 

I also entered the following as shown in How to completely uninstall docker :
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-compose-plugin
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
sudo rm -r ~/.docker

Then I entered the following to uninstall VS Code as shown in How do I uninstall Visual Studio Code? :
sudo apt purge code
sudo apt autoremove
rm -rf ~/.vscode ~/.config/Code

However after this, I entered:
sudo apt update

which returned:
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease                         
Ign:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease                 
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease               
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease                
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (stable/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (stable/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

My question is how to get rid of the "Err:6", "W:", "E:" and "N:" messages that were returned?
I am a beginner-intermediate in Ubuntu and VS code and, new to Docker. Thank you for your help in advance!

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Also don't forget, your release-upgrade path will soon disappear, as 23.04 will upgrade to 23.10 only until 23.10 reaches EOL which is only a few days away now ( https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/06/05/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/ ) as soon after EOL the meta release file will be modified which is read by the release-upgrade processes.  Many of your errors relate specifically to your attempting to use a release after EOL

Thank you for the tips! Are there any sites where I can post questions of versions of Ubuntu that have reached their EOL?

The on-topic link I provided includes SE Unix & Linux which covers releases that are ESM, EOSS, EOL & even development (what I'm using now) that are off-topic on this site.

W is a Warning and explains the reason:
is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu-lunar.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:1

so remove the duplicates and it goes away.
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release                        
404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3404:200:237::2 80]

that URL does not exist. Probably ros2 does not exist for "lunar" Either remove it or change "lunar" to a supported release.
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

will disappear after you fixed the previous one.

This helped. Thank you!
